# Javascript only - Conditional options not hiding on second iterant in CF7 form

Tags: javascript, html

Background - Total novice.

Problem:
So I have a CF7 form where the client either chooses Option A or Option B (Condition 1). If the client chooses Option B, then he/she is shown a dropdown list of countries (Condition 2) and based on country selection, a radio button list of languages (Condition 3).

Based on the suggestions here, I have got the form to run these conditionalities. The problem is occurring when we change the option.
So if client decides to change his selection in Condition 1 to Option A, I have got the form to reset Conditions 2 and 3 to blank and also hide Conditions 2 and 3.
However, if the client once again changes the selection in Condition 1 to Option B, then I am seeing the following:

1. If during previous interaction, no language (Condition 3) selection was made, then choosing Option B now correctly gives Condition 2 choice and based on Condition 2 choice, the list of languages as Condition 3.
2. If however during the previous interaction, the client had reached till condition 3 and had chosen a language, then re-selecting Option B shows blank dropdown (condition 2) which is correct but the previous list of languages in condition 3 which is incorrect as dropdown in condition 2 has already been reset.

The form is here: https://certifiedtranslationsindia.com/order-form/
under the source language section.

When the country dropdown is reset to blank, then why is the condition 3 languages from previous selection of the country still showing?

```html
`<li> <b>Is your document currently in English?* </b>[radio Source_English id:source_english_dropdown default:1 "Yes, it is an English document and I need it translated from English to another language" "No, it is in another language"] </li>
        <label id="issuer_country_dropdown"> <b> Document issued by </b> (Country where your document has been issued) [select issuer_country class:required include_blank "Afghanistan" "Aland Islands" "Albania"] </label>
<div id="radioButtonContainer">
    <ol>
  <li> [radio Source2 id:AFG class:required "Pashto" "Dari"] </li> 
  <li> [radio Source2 id:ALA class:required "Swedish" "Finnish"] </li> 
  <li> [radio Source2 id:ALB class:required "Albanian"] </li>
</div>`
```

```js
type = "text/javascript" 
  // Hide the non-English source options (issuer country) by default
  document.getElementById('issuer_country_dropdown').style.display == 'none';
// On every 'Change' of the drop down with the ID "source_english_dropdown" call the IssuerCountry function
document.getElementById('source_english_dropdown').addEventListener('click', IssuerCountry);

function IssuerCountry() {
  // Get the value of the selected drop down
  var radioText = document.querySelector('input[name="Source_English"]:checked').value;
  // If selected text matches 'No, it is in another language', display the Issuer Country list.
  if (radioText == 'No, it is in another language') {
    document.getElementById('issuer_country_dropdown').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('radioButtonContainer').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementsByName("issuer_country")[0].selectedIndex = 0
    document.getElementById('issuer_country_dropdown').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('radioButtonContainer').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('input[name="Source2"]:checked').checked = false;
  }
} 

  // Hide the various languages by default
document.getElementById("AFG").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("ALA").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("ALB").style.display = 'none';
// On every 'Change' of the drop down with the ID "country_dropdown" call the CountryType function
document.getElementById("issuer_country_dropdown").addEventListener("change", CountryType);

function CountryType() {
  // Get the value of the selected drop down
  var dropDownText = document.getElementsByName("issuer_country")[0].value;
  // If selected text matches Afghanistan, display the corresponding language list based on ISO code
  if (dropDownText == "Afghanistan") {
    document.getElementById("AFG").style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("AFG").style.display = 'none';
  }
  // If selected text matches Aland Islands, display the corresponding language list based on ISO code
  if (dropDownText == "Aland Islands") {
    document.getElementById("ALA").style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ALA").style.display = 'none';
  }
  // If selected text matches Albania, display the corresponding language list based on ISO code
  if (dropDownText == "Albania") {
    document.getElementById("ALB").style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ALB").style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share your current code. it is difficult to identify the problem based on condition only,

Comment: Shared the code pls. Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to reset your dropdown whenever user changes the first or second dropdown value and then after your can add rest of the logic in your onChange function.
Here is a sample code snippet.

```js
document.getElementById("first_dropdown").addEventListener("change", ()=>{
    reset();
});

function reset(){
    document.getElementById("second_dropdown").selectedIndex = 0;
    document.getElementById("third_dropdown").selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

```html
<label>First Dropdown</label>
<select id="first_dropdown">
  <option>-</option>
  <option>First</option>
  <option>Second</option>
  <option>Second</option>
</select>

<label>Second Dropdown</label>
<select id="second_dropdown">
  <option>-</option>
  <option>First</option>
  <option>Second</option>
</select>

<label>Third Dropdown</label>
<select id="third_dropdown">
  <option>-</option>
  <option>First</option>
  <option>Second</option>
</select>
```

**Edit:**
If you are saying that Translate Into radio options are not hiding while resetting the "Is your document currently in English?" options then you need to add below line in the change event handler along with resetting the dropdown value for Country.

```
document.getElementById("Source_Label").style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. Is the fact that condition 1 and condition 3 are radio buttons perhaps messing with the code?

Comment: I have updated the answer please check again Edit section.